# Posting Jupyter notebooks for blind review

Tags: jupyter

Is there an elegant way to post Jupyter notebooks for *blind review*, so that no author is identifiable? I could get a throwaway Google account or something, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Depending on the context, you could ask the editor if you can submit an .ipynb (to be shared with reviewers) along with your manuscript. Full disclosure, I've never heard of that being done, but why not!

Comment: Thanks! I'm in a field where I can't assume programming competence on the other end (or my end for that matter!). I'd love for them to be able to run the code "out of the box", even if they don't have python installed locally for example. I thought a site might be best for that.

Comment: I see. Well, I suppose you could ask the editor to host a Colab or something. This question seems like it ought to have some sort of answer -- as a reviewer I would certainly appreciate not having to code up a paper's approach from scratch to check it out.